# What is the source of Uttara Gita

Tags: krishna

There are several websites that mention uttara Gita (not to be mistaken with Uddava Gita from Srimad Bhagavatha), which is another conversation between Sri Krishna and Arjuna. Can someone help with the source of that Gita.

Comment: [This](http://www.celextel.org/othervedantabooks/uttaragita.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Triyugi Narayan Mani. I have found the Uttara Gita text in several places but am unable find the source, the scripture that actually contains the text. Bhagavad Gita has Mahabharatha as its parent text, Uddava Gita has Srimad Bhagavatha as its parent text. Similarly, knowing the parent text of Uttara Gita is my query and my quest.

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of sources saying it's from the Brahmanda Purana.

Comment: Thanks Keshav. I guess its difficult to find the exact source so that we know the context (adjacent slokas) of the discussion.

Comment: Uddhava Gita is not a conversation between Krishna and Arjuna. It is conversation between Krishna and his friend/devotee Uddhava.

Comment: Uttara Gita is traditionally traced to the Ashvamedhika parva of the Mahabharatam

Comment: @Vivikta why don't you post that as an answer?  it seems like an answer no?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan why don't you post that as an answer? it seems like an answer no?